# looking for some sort of an RTF viewer

Tags: rtf

I want to do some investigation on RTF specification and see what happens when I say put a bulleted list, what happens when I press Enter, etc...
So I was wondering if there is a simple tool that on one part of it I can just start tpying a formatted text and one another part of it, it shows me the rtf version of what I am typing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could write this in C# pretty easily. Simply display a form with two text boxes: The left side being a regular [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) (probably with [`MultiLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff.aspx) set to `true`), and the right side being a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx).  Then, just handle the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event in either box, and update the opposite box with the newly edited text.